# How to fire an event on payment received in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Im using one page checkout and I need to pass few information after payment has been successfully made. I have used sales_order_payment_pay, checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after, sales_order_payment_place_end & checkout_onepage_controller_success_action events. But these events are triggered as soon as clicking on place order. Even if the payment is failure also its triggering that event. I need to pass information only on successful payment.

Answer (score 2):

`sales_order_payment_place_end` should be good enough. Just add whatever logic you need to use. You can grab the `$payment` from the `$observer` and the `$order` from the `$payment`

Try looking into `$payment->getAmountAuthorized` If the payment succeeded this should be greater then 0.

EDIT: $observer->getEvent()->getPayment(); (should work)

Comment: "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" event did the trick. Thanks guys. To get order id I used $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

Comment: @Palanikumar: Two things: One: Note that if an admin places an order it may or may not hit this event. Not sure if this matters for you. That is why I suggested sales_order_payment_place_end (Also you said 'payment has been successfully made').
Secondly: either give one of us the correct answer, or create an answer yourself and select it. Be Helpful!

Comment: @SH- what's the code I need to actually get the $payment variable out of the $observer?

Comment: @DanHanly: added info

Comment: @SH- in the end, it was simply $observer->getPayment()

Comment: @DanHanly: Both should work. The Event is the container for all the observers of the thrown event. Each Observer Generally has the objects passed also.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Status of an Order changes After Payment notification. You can watch for Status change have a Look at:

http://www.cartware.de/blog/detail/article/kein-magento-event-fuer-statusaenderung/

Its written in german Language but by watching the Code you may get the clue